# Why array contains '&string' as value type?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have this string array:

[image]

I would like to know why it contains '&' in it value types, is there any difference between '&string' and 'string' type?

Comment: probably a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&string` means the element contains a reference to a variable containing the string, rather than just the string. This would happen if you did:

```
$num = '14005028';
$array['curp'] = &$num;
```

A reference is an alias to another variable, so assigning to `$num` will change what's in `$array['curp']`, and vice versa.

See [References Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) in the PHP documentation.

Comment: But technically references in PHP are actually not the references you can do in C.

Comment: @AndreFerraz I never said anything about C.

Comment: I know you didn't. By nature, assigning a variable e.g $a = $b, will be passed as a reference in PHP both variables refer to the same zval and are treated equally by PHP. PHP is very weird in a way.

Comment: @AndreFerraz Unless `$b` contains an object, that assignment makes a copy. PHP optimizes copies by using copy-on-write, but that's an invisible implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

It means your array index 'curp' design a value passed by reference.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

example:

```
$var1 = "string by reference";
$var2 = " string"
$array = ["var1" => &$var1, "var2" => $var2];
var_dump($array);
```